# How to change the PARSER_FORMATTER when using python's argh library

Tags: python, scope, python-module, argh

Using the [Argh](http://argh.readthedocs.io/) library for Python I want to provide another PARSER_FORMATTER when I dispatch my function with `argh.dispatch_command`.

I tried:

```
import argh
import argparse

argh.PARSER_FORMATTER = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter

def myfunct(arg, param=None):
    pass # here my working code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argh.dispatch_command(myfunct)
```

But when called with `--help` the resulting program still sprints
default values. So it still seems to use Argh's `CustomFormatter`
instead of argparse's `RawTextHelpFormatter` I try to provide.

Strangely when I use `set_default_command` and provide the parser myself, it works:

```
import argh
import argparse

argh.PARSER_FORMATTER = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter

def myfunct(arg, param=None):
    pass # here my working code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
         formatter_class=argh.PARSER_FORMATTER)
    argh.set_default_command(parser, myfunct)
    argh.dispatch(parser)
```

So the problem must relate to *internal visibility* of `PARSER_FORMATTER` in Argh. How can I change `argh.PARSER_FORMATTER` for the Argh module itself, so that `argh.dispatch_command` uses it? This *should* be possible, or am I on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monkey-patching external libraries is not recommended because it makes your code fragile. `argh.ArghParser` is a subclass of `ArgumentParser`, so you can simply pass your constant to its constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this behavior because Dispatching.py imports the `PARSER_FORMATTER` [constant into its own namespace](https://github.com/neithere/argh/blob/dcd3253f2994400a6a58a700c118c53765bc50a4/argh/dispatching.py#L24) at import time and subsequently, dispatch_command and dispatch_commands functions [refer to the local constant](https://github.com/neithere/argh/blob/dcd3253f2994400a6a58a700c118c53765bc50a4/argh/dispatching.py#L304) to get the formatter class.

To achieve what you want, the library would need to make an explicit choice to refer to the value in `argh.constants` namespace. [Illustration](https://github.com/neithere/argh/compare/master...yogeshg:argh:illustration?expand=1). Until and unless that happens, the following code snippet may be helpful:

```
import argparse
import argh

# argh.PARSER_FORMATTER = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
argh.dispatching.PARSER_FORMATTER = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter

def myfunct(arg, param=None):
    pass # here my working code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argh.dispatch_command(myfunct)
```